# Is there a way to use tensorflow.saved_model.load() for inference only without the full tensorflow python library

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, inference

I need to do inference. No training, just plain inference.

In python3, right now my very-basic tensorflow "inference-only" code is doing:

```
import tensorflow as tf  # This is a 600MB library (at version 2.5)
from PIL import Image
import io

model = tf.saved_model.load('models/some-version')
infer = model.signatures['serving_default']
image = Image.open('someFile.jpg')
bytes = io.BytesIO()
image.save(bytes, format='JPEG')
inputs = [bytes.getvalue()]
predictions = infer(inputs=tf.constant(inputs))
```

This works fine. BUT my problem is: this tensorflow python3 library is WAY too big! Approximately 600MB right now. And everytime a new tensorflow version gets released, it gets bigger and bigger! With tensorflow 2.3 (that was using swig instead of pybind) the library was roughly 300MB. Then it got to 400, 500, and recently 600MB (version 2.5)!

And when I do the same inference calls using golang bindings (instead of python), all I need is the libtensorflow.so.2 (275MB) and libtensorflow_framework.so.2 (25MB) files which are way smaller than the current 600MB folder (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow).

So my real question is: In python3, can I do inference using tensorflow without all that bloat?

There used to be a contrib.predictor module, but that was in tensorflow up to 1.15, no longer available with tensorflow V2. And sure there is always tensorflow_lite, but those are not the same. In golang, I can use the "real" TF bindings without so much bloat (I mean, it is still 275MB+25MB, but this is still less than 600MB and it does not keep growing every new release).

Has anybody been able to keep library size in check while using tensorflow 2.5 in python3 to do only inference (no training)?

If there is any "contrib" module in python to do so I would gladly use it.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need GPU support? If not, you can use the much smaller tensorflow-cpu via pip.

Comment: This is already the cpu version (no cuda support, -cpu). The gpu version is twice the size (amazing :()

Comment: I see. You can take a look at ONNX runtime, which is purpose built for machine learning inference. I haven’t used it myself, but I assume is it relatively lightweight.

Comment: The ONNX runtime is actually over 500MB, so it is not a lot "lighter" than the tensorflow full python3 module (600MB, plus another 50MB for numpy), and it is even bigger than the base libtensorflow.so ~300MB standalone/monolithic library (for C bindings and golang bindings). Thanks for the idea though! I appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, correction: I actually tried recompiling ONNX with proper release flags and the resulting library is around 13MB, so that would be a viable replacement (to a tensorflow-model-based system). Since I don't choose the model we use (I just "infer" on it, I do not "train" it) I cannot use ONNX out-of-the-box, I would have to use tf2onnx or something similar, which would affect our results. But still a valid option! Just not immediately working out-of-the-box. I might just convert our model from tensorflow to tensorflow-lite instead, its library is less than one MB (even better than 13MB).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up building a simple python wrapper around the C bindings, with only two simple functions: the first one to "load" the model using TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel() and the second one to "infer" on my inputs using TF_SessionRun(). The result is a much faster startup time (it only takes 76ms to "load" the model using the C bindings in python, while it takes well over 5 seconds to load it using the full tensorflow python module, I guess due to a lot more "checks" being performed? weird, but I will take it since it is an improvements). The resulting docker image size is 300MB instead of almost one GB. So this works for me, for now. I am just a bit disappointed that the tensorflow project seems to care so little about disk space. Everything else seems ok!

Comment: In the realm of big data, 1 GB and 5 seconds of load time is  quite inconsequential compared to the usual runtime and size of models themselves, which is likely why TF doesn't care so much about that bloat

Comment: It would help future readers if you included the code you used to answer your question.

Comment: In the realm of big data, productions cost go way up when you start a spot instance (10 times cheaper than sagemaker or other) and it takes 5 minutes instead of 5 seconds to start it. So if you process millions of pictures per minutes like we do, (and that IS the realm of big data) it does matter. A lot. In the realm of universities "big data", thesis and white papers, I agree, 1GB and 5 seconds are meaningless.

Comment: I actually think that is why tensorflow has so much bloat: it is much more meant to be a thesis proof than a real-world price-efficient tool (hence the existence of so many alternatives such as the ONNX runtime, pytorch (well, just as big but anyhow) and dozens of other ML/AI tools).

Comment: And I also think that in most cases the reason why TF does not care is most people using do not pay out of their own company-pockets the processing (and spinup time) of the machines performing the training/inference/other.

Comment: @Reggie:- Can you please share the code?